# Powershell.exe infected by “C2/Generic-B” Virus/spyware

Tags: virus, sophos

Good day everyone!

I'm scanning all the local computers with Sophos anti-virus via Windows Server.

I can remotely remove most of the viruses or malware that Sophos detects on other PCs.

Sophos also showing that there is a **"Virus/spyware"** called **"C2/Generic-B"** located on **"C:\Windows\System32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"** and I have to remove it manually.

How do I remove it? What is it? Should I remove it or just let it stay like that?

Comment: Start uploading the file here: https://www.virustotal.com/en/

Comment: This sounds like a false positive

Answer (score 0):

[C2/Generic-B](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/C2~Generic-B.aspx) is a detection from Malicious Traffic Detection, and means the process is connecting to a Command and Control server for a bot-net. Given that it is powershell being detected as the executable, that suggests that it is a powershell script that is running and connecting to a C&C server. It suggests the machine is running a bot-net program of some kind.

https://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/C2~Generic-B.aspx